Proof of Zarantonello's Inequality
This question is from Brezis's Functional Analysis, exercise 5.23.

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and let $T: H \rightarrow H$ be a (nonlinear) contraction.
Assume that $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_n \in \mathbb{R}$ are such that $\alpha_i \geq 0 \; \forall i$ and $\sum \limits_{i = 1}^n \alpha_i = 1$.
Assume that $u_1, u_2, \ldots, u_n \in H$ and set
$$ \sigma = \sum \limits_{i = 1}^n \alpha_i u_i. $$
Prove that
$$ \left | T \sigma - \sum \limits_{i = 1}^n \alpha_i Tu_i \right |^2 \leq \frac{1}{2} \sum \limits_{i,j = 1}^n \alpha_i \alpha_j \left [ |u_i - u_j|^2 - |Tu_i - Tu_j|^2 \right ]. $$
[ Hint: Write
$$ \left | T \sigma - \sum \limits_{i = 1}^n \alpha_i Tu_i \right |^2 = \sum \limits_{i, j = 1}^n \alpha_i \alpha_j (T\sigma - Tu_i, T\sigma - Tu_j) $$
and use the identity $(a, b) = \frac{1}{2}(|a|^2 + |b|^2 - |a - b|^2).$]
What can one deduce when $T$ is an isometry (i.e. $|Tu - Tv| = |u - v| \; \forall u, v \in H$)?

So far, I have been able to prove that
$$ \left | T \sigma - \sum \limits_{i = 1}^n \alpha_i Tu_i \right |^2 = \sum \limits_{i, j = 1}^n \alpha_i \alpha_j (T\sigma - Tu_i, T\sigma - Tu_j) . $$
Using $(a, b) = \frac{1}{2}(|a|^2 + |b|^2 - |a - b|^2)$, I write
\begin{align}
\sum \limits_{i, j = 1}^n \alpha_i \alpha_j (T\sigma - Tu_i, T\sigma - Tu_j)
& = \frac{1}{2} \sum \limits_{i, j = 1}^n \alpha_i \alpha_j \left ( |T \sigma - Tu_i|^2 + |T\sigma - Tu_j|^2 - |Tu_i - Tu_j|^2 \right) \\
& = \sum \limits_{i = 1}^n \alpha_i |T \sigma - Tu_i|^2 - \frac{1}{2} \sum \limits_{i, j = 1}^n \alpha_i \alpha_j |Tu_i - Tu_j|^2 . 
\end{align}
From here, I want to show that
\begin{equation}
|T \sigma - Tu_i|^2 \leq \frac{1}{2} \sum \limits_{j = 1}^n \alpha_j|u_i - u_j|^2 .  
\end{equation}
If I can show the above inequality, we immediately obtain the answer.
My question is as follows: Is this inequality correct? If so, how would one go about proving it? Am I on the right track, or should I explore some other approach? Any help would be appreciated!
Solution: Building off the hint given by @gerw.
Fix $1 \leq i \leq n$, and note that
\begin{align}
|\sigma - u_i|^2 
& = | \sum \limits_{j = 1}^n \alpha_j (u_j - u_i)|^2 \\ 
& = \left ( \sum \limits_{j = 1}^n \alpha_j (u_j - u_i), \sum \limits_{\ell = 1}^n \alpha_{\ell} (u_{\ell} - u_i) \right ) \\ 
& = \sum \limits_{j, \ell = 1}^n \alpha_j \alpha_{\ell} (u_j - u_i, u_{\ell} - u_i ) \\ 
& = \frac{1}{2} \sum \limits_{j, \ell = 1}^n \alpha_j \alpha_{\ell} \left ( |u_j - u_i|^2 + |u_{\ell} - u_i|^2 - |u_j - u_{\ell}|^2 \right ) . 
\end{align}
Thus,
\begin{align}
\sum \limits_{i = 1}^n \alpha_i |\sigma - u_i|^2
& = \sum \limits_{i = 1}^n \alpha_i \left ( \frac{1}{2} \sum \limits_{j, \ell = 1}^n \alpha_j \alpha_{\ell} \left ( |u_j - u_i|^2 + |u_{\ell} - u_i|^2 - |u_j - u_{\ell}|^2 \right ) \right ) \\
& = \frac{1}{2} \sum \limits_{i, j, \ell = 1}^n \alpha_i \alpha_j \alpha_{\ell} \left ( |u_j - u_i|^2 + |u_{\ell} - u_i|^2 - |u_j - u_{\ell}|^2 \right ) . 
\end{align}
Since we're summing over $i, j$, and $\ell$, the last two terms cancel out and we're left with
$$ \sum \limits_{i = 1}^n \alpha_i |\sigma - u_i|^2 = \frac{1}{2} \sum \limits_{i, j = 1}^n \alpha_i \alpha_j |u_j - u_i|^2 . $$
Along with the fact that $T$ is a contraction, this gives the result.

It seems you haven't yet used the fact that $T$ is a contraction.

Hint: You have
$$
\sum_i \alpha_i | \sigma - u_i|^2
=
\frac12 \sum_{i,j} \alpha_i \alpha_j |u_i - u_j|^2.
$$
I do not think that your desired inequality holds, you need the sum over $i$.

I thought I was able to prove your equality, but I haven't been able to yet. Can you explain how you derived that expression?

In the inequality you have proven, we can use $|T\sigma - Tu_i|\le|\sigma-u_i|$. The equality in my answer is then just needed to complete the exercise. You can prove it by expanding all the inner products.

Thank you! I edited my question with the solution based off of this hint. Let me know what you think!

Yes, looks good.
